# Increasing a counter with alarm manager while app is still opened in background

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager

I'm currently working on implementing notifications with an alarm manager in my app.

I want to lets say push 10 notifications. Each time a notification gets pushed I want to increase a counter and save it as a shared preferences value for later so that I can access the counter the next time the app opens.

It is almost working fine.

When I send the notifications and the app is fully closed (not opened in background) and I open the app again the counter is restored with the correct value, i.e. 5 notifications were sent -> counter=4 (0-4).

However if the app isn't fully closed (still opened in background) and the notifications get pushed I can see that the counter is increasing without any problem but when I go back to the app, somehow the counter is 0 (in my case I tried for example to print out a log message containing the counter with the onResume() function).

When I fully close the app and reopen it the counter is correct again.

I've been stuck for a couple of days now and still haven't figured it out. Help will be very appreciated!

**NotificationReceiver class**

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

private static String TAG = "message";
public static int counter;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SecondClass sc = new SecondClass();
    SavedSharedPreferences ssp = new SavedSharedPreferences();
    //getting saved counter
    ssp.getSavedItems(context);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (counter>=10){
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: counter = 10+");

        sc.endAlarm(context);
        counter=0;
        saveCounter(context);
    }

    if (counter<10) {
        Intent repeatingIntent = new Intent(context, SecondClass.class);
        repeatingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, counter, repeatingIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.icon)
                .setTicker("Ticker")
                .setContentText("Content Text")
                .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        nm.notify(counter, builder.build());

        //once notification was sent, increase counter and save it
        counter++;
        saveCounter(context);
    }

}

//save number of times notification was send
public static void saveCounter(Context ctx){
    SavedSharedPreferences sSP = new SavedSharedPreferences();
    sSP.saveNormalInt(counter, sSP.theCounter, ctx);
}
}
```

**SecondClass class**

```
public class SecondClass extends Fragment{
     @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    NotificationReceiver nr = new NotificationReceiver();

    SavedSharedPreferences ssp = new SavedSharedPreferences();
    ssp.getSavedItems(getContext());

    Log.d(TAG, "onResume: counter: "+nr.counter);

    if (nr.counter>10){
        nr.counter=0;
        nr.saveCounter(getContext());
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    NotificationReceiver nr = new NotificationReceiver();

    startButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_start);
    stopButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_stop);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nr.counter = 0;
            nr.saveCounter(getContext());
                //starting
                startNotifications();
            }
        }
    });
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            endAlarm(getContext());
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

private void startNotifications() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    NotificationReceiver nr = new NotificationReceiver();

    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute+1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), nr.counter, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10*1000, pendingIntent);
}

public void endAlarm(Context ctx){
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    NotificationReceiver nr = new NotificationReceiver();

    for (int i=0; i<=nr.counter;i++) {

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
}

}
```

And how I get saved counter in SavedSharedPreferences:

```
public final String theCounter= "THE_COUNTER";

 public void loadCounter(Context ctx) {
    NotificationReceiver nr = new NotificationReceiver();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    nr.counter = prefs.getInt(theCounter, 0);
}
```

Comment: can you try using ctx.getApplicationContext() instead of just ctx ? not sure if it'll help or not, but no harm trying.

Comment: @AngelKoh first of all thanks for your help! In which class do you mean?

Comment: when you save and load into/from the shared preferences. just in case the context from the broadcast receiver is different from the context from the activity

Comment: @AngelKoh unfortunately not working :(

Comment: dude use `SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` to define the   sharedpreference and then get the object of sharedpreference by using `getPreference()` and use `SharedPreferences.Editor` object to commit or retrive data from sharedperfereces object

Comment: @jatDevta could you please explain it more detailed or with some code snippets!

Comment: **first create object **  `SharedPreferences pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` **now get preference object and save your counterValue** `SharedPreference pref=context.getSharedPreferences("counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreference.Editor  editor =pref.edit(); 
 
    editor.putString("count", countValue);
    editor.commit();`  **get value from sharedPreference**  `SharedPreference pref=context.getSharedPreferences("counter", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); and int counterValue=pref.getString("count",0);`

Comment: Why do I have to create the first object and then not even using it? Why is the first object "SharedPreferences" and the other two "SharedPreference"? And what's the difference between "counter" and "count"? And where should I put each statement? Sorry, it isn't very clear to me. @jatDevta

Comment: hey ! other two are also "SharedPreferences" ,it was just a typos, 1. we are creating the object so that we can use it anywhere 2. here "counter" is your preference name and the "count" is name of your name of  variable you are storing in SharedPreferences object, **you should put First statement in your `onCreate()` method in **MainActivity** and push value when you need to increment the counter , and retrieve value of "count"  inside your `loadCounter()` method

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's still not working. The counter is still 0 when re-opening the app :( @jatDevta